# Philippines experiences/enjoys tropical climate

Tags: word-usage

In my exam I chose

> Philippines experiences tropical climate.

instead of

> Philippines enjoys tropical climate.

However, my teacher said that the answer is otherwise. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English, the core sentence would be constructed like this:

"The Philippines have a tropical climate."
"The Philippines enjoy a tropical climate."

(I wouldn't use the word "experience" as that word is really only used for people.)

However to answer your question, the use of the word "enjoy" indicates that whatever is being referred to is pleasant.  For example, you could say:

"We were enjoying the warm sunshine."

.. but I don't think you could say:

"We were enjoying the freezing rain and howling winds."

So the question is, do you think a tropical climate is something to be enjoyed?

Comment: the word Philippines should be used with have or has ? I really wonder why

Comment: @CinderNguyen : I went to Wikipedia to confirm the doubt and it says ***The Philippines**, officially known as the Republic of the Philippines (Filipino: Republika ng Pilipinas), **is** a sovereign island country in Southeast Asia situated in the western Pacific Ocean. **It consists** of about 7,641 islands that are categorized broadly under three main geographical divisions from north to south: Luzon, Visayas, and Mindanao.* It should definitely be **has**.

Comment: But "<geographical location> enjoys a <adjective> climate" is a very idiomatic, common usage.  For example, "[The coast of Tunisia...enjoys a mild climate all year](https://books.google.com/books?id=Boo4GQdE-bcC&pg=PA7&dq=enjoys+a+mild+climate&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-ocbz78LMAhWFmx4KHcvrCFgQ6AEIJjAC)" or "[The western coast enjoys a Mediterranean climate](https://books.google.com/books?id=qlEJAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA274&dq=enjoys+a+warm+climate&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYpbGU8MLMAhUJJx4KHRX0CEMQ6AEITDAI)".  As you say, it usually depends on whether you think the particular climate is enjoyable or not!

Comment: @7_R3X One can never totally rely on Wikipedia for correct grammar, or correct anything for that matter. It's always best to get a reference that confirms what Wikipedia claims. Besides that, it does not "definitely" have to be *has*. *The Philippines* is conceptually plural (the Philippine islands) and thus *have* is also permissible.

Answer (score 1):

The word [enjoy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enjoy) in this context means **to have something good or lucky**- it is normally used about positive things.

On the other hand, if you [experience](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/experience) something, **it happens to you, or you feel it**. It is usually used about negative things.

So you could say

> The Philippines has **experienced** the worst typhoon in 20 years

But you would say

> The Philippines **enjoys** a tropical climate